# Raspberry Pi Pico - How to install libraries using rshell and command line

Tags: raspberry-pi, raspbian

I would like to use a DHT11 and I have downloaded the git repository for the library from Adafruit. I know how to add libraries using Thonny, but I am coding my Pico on a headless pi zero over ssh so I need a way to install libraries from the command line or rshell.

Do any of you know how to do this?

thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The answer is to run rshel on the host `rshell -p /dev/ttyACM0 --buffer-size 512` and then just copy the module to `/pyboard/lib/`. Then run repl and do a `CTL + d` to soft reboot the Pico.